# AOE scheduler Multiple tasks with the same job code were piling up. Skipping execution of duplicates

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, schedule

Since yesterday I have a problem with one cronjob that is not running anymore. This cronjob was working fine for several months and yesterday we had to stop it and then re enabled it 6 hours later. I'm using AOE scheduler and in the Schedule task list view I see that the **cronjob was missed** and the message says:

> Multiple tasks with the same job code were piling up. Skipping execution of duplicates

This is strange because looking at the schedule there are no multiple tasks with the same job code at that given time.

This message seems to be coming from here:

> app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ScheduleManager.php

```
foreach ($schedules as $key => $schedule) {
    /* @var Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule $schedule */
    if (isset($seenJobs[$schedule->getJobCode()])) {
        $schedule
            ->setMessages('Multiple tasks with the same job code were piling up. Skipping execution of duplicates.')
                ->setStatus(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule::STATUS_SKIP_PILINGUP)
            ->save();
    } else {
        $seenJobs[$schedule->getJobCode()] = 1;
    }
}
```

I tried several things, like running the cron manually using magerun (this works well) stoping and starting again the cron, re generating the schedule but I get the same problem. Any ideas why this is happening? Is just strange since it was working fine for so long.

Comment: Did you solve this problems yet? I had same error after i have problem in cron. How can i run missed cron jobs of magento?

Comment: I did not solve it, I just moved my cronjob to the crontab